# Checking out only certain folders from SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm looking to checkout several projects (organized in different folders at different hierarchies) from a SVN repositories.  But all projects are placed under one top level root folder.
Most projects have  trunk, tags, branches folders. Some have project files directly in the main folder without 'trunk' etc..

How can checkout only the trunk folders of all the projects and exclude tags, branches etc but all at once automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

Check out each project, but only the most immediate children (not fully recursive) (`svn checkout URL PATH --depth immediates`). Then, for each trunk, run `svn update --set-depth infinity` and the full tree under `trunk` will be populated.

If you want to check out from the root (which I don't recommend), do the same thing - check out the immediate children, then `svn up --set-depth infinity project1/trunk`, `svn up --set-depth infinity project2/trunk` and so on.

Comment: How can I checkout all the projects in one go recursively?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean by running the svn checkout command just once and checkout all projects at once.

Comment: Only if you do it from the root of the repository, then get a list of all the projects and `svn update PATH1 PATH2 PATH3` (but I'm not certain that'll work, haven't tested). Otherwise, you'll have to iterate through each project (script it, it'll be quicker/easier).